# Most efficient way to record data and simultaneously check for conditions?

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write a python code for the rapspbery pi to control a very particular apparatus which is a lever (that has a rotary encoder at its end) and a few LEDs. 
Essentially one pulls the lever to a particular range of positions and when done correctly an LED will turn on indicating you are in the goal position. 
The lever may be moved within a certain range of encoder counts and you will still succeed in completing a trial.
My **question** is, what is the best way to record lever position data while at the same time being able to check whether or not the lever is in the correct range of positions?

I had already written software for a simpler version of this program which simply uses a switch instead of a rotary encoder as a lever. The advantage of the encoder is that I can get very precise measurements of the lever position and thus have even more data! I can think of ways to record the data, the only problem is it will be slow. I am thinking of using a *nested while loop* in which the loop will check and record the position of the lever, however I am afraid this may option will have a very low sampling rate.

I am also thinking of using **threads** to achieve this goal, however I have no clue how to be able to do this using threads, since I have never used them before.

I already have the software and hardware that interfaces with the encoder itself, I am able to obtain very nice data of the lever position however I would like to be able to record as many of these data points as possible while at the same time still be able to check whether the lever is in the correct range of positions.

I would really appreciate it if you could show me a simple code that does this and I should be able to implement it to my code.

Here is a simple example of how I am currently thinking of writing the code:

```
minCorrectPos = 100
maxCorrectPos = 200
timeToHoldLever = 5.0 #Seconds

while True:
    currentPos = encoder.readEncoderPos() #Function returns int
    writeToFile(str(currentPos)) #Records the data pos of the lever. I want this to happen as often as physically possible so as to lose the least amount of data.
    if currentPos < minCorrectPos or currentPos > maxCorrectPos:
        print 'Lever is out of range, wrong trial'
        writeData(timestamp)
    if time.time()-t_trialBegin > timeToHoldLever:
        print 'Lever has been held for enough time within correct range of positions. Rewarding person.'
        break
    #... 
    #Potentially checking for more things, like status of subject, whether he or she is still touching the lever, etc.
```

The reason I don't like the code above is because I am afraid I am going to lose data since the raspberry pi may not be able to poll the position of the lever fast enough due to the ongoing while loop (slow sampling rate). That is why I think threads may be the correct way to solve this problem, since I will have a separate thread running dedicated exclusively to recording the lever position given the name of the subject pulling the lever. Sadly I need help writing that type of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of threads, because the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) prevents Python from executing threads concurrently, even with multiple cores. The `multiprocessing` module avoids this limitation.

Here's a small example that shows how you could have a subprocess dedicated to writing the `currentPos` to a file, by using a `multiprocessing.Pipe` to send `currentPos` between the parent and child processes.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def writeToFile(conn):
    with open(filename, "a") as f: # Just leave the file open for performance reasons.
        while True:
            currentPos = conn.recv()        
            f.write("{}\n".format(currentPos))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent_conn, child_conn = mp.Pipe()
    p = mp.Process(target=writeToFile, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    while True:
        currentPos = encoder.readEncoderPos()
        parent_conn.send(currentPos)
        if currentPos < minCorrectPos or currentPos > maxCorrectPos:
            print 'Lever is out of range, wrong trial'
            writeData(timestamp)
        if time.time()-t_trialBegin > timeToHoldLever:
            print 'Lever has been held for enough time within correct range of positions. Rewarding pe'
            break
```

Note that despite my earlier statement about Python not handling threads well, they may perform pretty favorably compared to `multiprocessing` in this particular example. This is because the subprocess is primarily doing I/O, which allows the GIL to be released. You could try a similar implementation with the `threading` module and compare the performance.

Also, you may want to have `writeToFile` only actually execute the `f.write` after every N number of `currentPos` values have been received. File I/O is slow, so doing fewer, larger writes may perform better for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer:
How about adding the current position of the encoder to a list, such that I don't have to write as many times as possible (like you said), and then when the trial is over I can write the list to a file?
Also, if I understand this correctly, every time this loop runs, it will send the lever position to the other process and as soon as it sends the pos, the loop will continue, regardless of whether the pos has been written to a file?]

Comment: @ch0l1n3 If you can delay writing to a file at all (that includes `writeData`, if that's writing to a file, too) until the trial is done, then you probably don't even need concurrency, since file I/O is by far the slowest thing going on here. Your understanding of what my example is done is correct. `writeToFile` is running in a separate process, so it doesn't block your `while True` loop from working.

Comment: Thanks! Got it! I ended up using events! I have a function that continually keeps adding leverPos to a list (I ended with a sample rate of 1kHz!!) and then all I do is start a process that calls that function then I use an event handler on my main function such that when the time is reached or if they subjects screws up the position of the lever, the process is called off, and when it does it immediately writes the whole list to a file taking on average 80ms to do so, which is a significant amount of time given that I want to really have the highest sample rate possible for the whole program!

Comment: Parallelising will not help on a Raspberry Pi. It only has one core, so executing tasks in parallel will only add communication overhead. You could try to translate your code with Cython, and get a big speed improvement.